# pandoc tex to docx with biblatex

Tags: pandoc, msword, biblatex-chicago, latex-to-word

I'm looking for a relatively easy converter for tex to docx format (unfortunately I have a supervisor who insists on a word version).

I can get a fairly decent conversion using pandoc
`pandoc --bibliography references.bib --csl=chicago-note-bibliography.csl -o OUT.docx IN.tex`, however, I notice it ignores commands like `\citetitle` and `\citeauthor`. This makes the word version look like it is full of typos.

Is there a way to use native biblatex with pandoc so that commands are interpreted properly using the style defined in the document? Alternatively, is there a better tool for creating word documents from tex? I don't care how ugly it looks as it is just for my supervisor. As long as the typos are mine and not the converters I am happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandoc supports only a subset of biblatex cite commands (this is a known issue, cf. https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2335).

supported:

- **`\autocite`**
- **`\autocite*`**
- `\cite`
- `\parencite`
- `\Parencite`
- `\footcite`
- `\footcitetext`
- `\textcite`
- `\Textcite`
- `\smartcite`
- `\Smartcite`
- `\citeyear`

unsupported:

- `\Cite`
- `\fullcite`
- `\footfullcite`
- `\Citeauthor`
- `\citetitle`

How the output is rendered depends on the csl file you are using.

---

There are two general approaches how you can solve your problem:

1. Rewrite all unsupported citations using the supported commands and/or manual additions.
2. Leave everything as it is and convert the PDF to DOCX which can be done with `Adobe Acrobat`, `Abiword`, `LibreOffice`, and `OpenOffice`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if you provided a MWE. Based on the info provided the solution might be to edit your source tex to use `\cite{author}` instead of `\citetitle` or `\citeauthor`.

Here is a MWE:

```
\section{Lorem Ipsum}\label{lorem-ipsum}

``Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet \cite{ref-chou2003interactivity}, consectetur, adipisci velit\ldots{}''

\section*{References}\label{references}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}

\hypertarget{refs}{}
\hypertarget{ref-chou2003interactivity}{}
Chou, Chien. 2003. ``Interactivity and Interactive Functions in
Web-Based Learning Systems: A Technical Framework for Designers.''
\emph{British Journal of Educational Technology} 34 (3). Wiley Online
Library: 265--79.
```

And render with `pandoc document.tex -f latex -t docx -o  document.docx`

Hope this helps.